# Attempting to numerically integrate two nonlinear ODEs to generate a model for oscillations of a fluid column

Tags: computational-physics, oscillators, differential-equations, models

This question is related to the paper located at https://doi.org/10.1063/1.1476670.

I am attempting to model the oscillations of a fluid column. I have 2 ODEs that describe the oscillations, namely: $z\ddot{z}+\dot{z}^2=1-z$ (for $dz>0$ i.e. when the fluid is rising) and $z\ddot{z}=1-z$ (for $dz<0$ i.e. when the fluid is falling).

These can be integrated to: $\frac{1}{2} z^{2} \dot{z}^{2}+\frac{1}{3} z^{3}-\frac{1}{2} z^{2}=A$ and $\frac{1}{2} \dot{z}^{2}+z-\ln z=B$ respectively.

I am trying to integrate these ODEs numerically in Python and join up the successive solutions to the rising/falling regimes governed by each equation. The expected output should look like the solid line in the graph below:

[image]

I am using Python's scipy.integrate.solve_ivp() function, and I keep getting a problem where the algorithm breaks due to encountering a square root of a negative number (the square root is from rearranging the ODEs for $\dot{z}$). I'm a bit out of my depth as I haven't done anything like this before and no matter what I try, I can't seem to make things work.

Comment: to avoid the sqrt  problem transfer the equations to first order differential equations with those equations $\begin{aligned}\dfrac{dz}{dt}=y_{1}\,~,
z=y_{2}\end{aligned}$ you can use now any numerical integration method like RK4 for example

Comment: Thanks, I tried doing this and managed to successfully reproduce the model. I found out that the main problem I was having wasn't actually encountering negative square roots (with hindsight, this was an avoidable side effect of the main problem), but actually that the equations were stiff and diverging. Reducing the step size and using the specialised 'Radau' algorithm for stiff ODEs allowed me to solve the ODEs successfully without divergence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Eli in a comment, I first converted the ODEs to two pairs of coupled first order ODEs. These ODEs turned out to be stiff. Using a smaller step size and the 'Radau' solving algorithm allowed me to successfully reproduce the model.